# Autodesk BIM360: Folder Creation returns 400 Bad request

Tags: autodesk-data-management

I called the POST-Folder Method via Postman with a JSON body according to [this example](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-data.management-nodejs-transfer.storage/blob/master/server/forge/integration.js#L137). But I only receive the message "400 Bad Request" without any explanations. This is what my request looks like:

**The service adress:**

> https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.5823d0b2-0000-0000-00/commands

**The HTTP-header**

```
Authorization: Bearer 2_legged_token
Content-Type:  application/vnd.api+json
```

**The JSON-Body**

```
{
   "jsonapi": {
      "version": "1.0"
   },
   "data": {
      "type": "commands",
      "attributes": {
         "extension": {
            "type": "commands:autodesk.core:CreateFolder",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "data": {
               "requiredAction": "create"
            }
         }
      },
      "relationships": {
         "resources": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "type": "folders",
                  "id": "1"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "included": [
      {
         "type": "folders",
         "id": "1",
         "attributes": {
            "name": "test",
            "extension": {
               "type": "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder",
               "version": "1.0.0"
            }
         },
         "relationships": {
            "parent": {
               "data": {
                  "type": "folders",
                  "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.Ai*****"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**The response**

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "f1266e76-a37e-400b-bff6-de84b11cdb00",
            "status": "400",
            "detail": "BadRequest"
        }
    ]
}
```

**What I have found out so far:**

- The project id is right. When I take a wrong project id I receive a different error.
- The Json is also valid.
- When I take a (surely) wrong parent-folder-urn I'll receive the same error message. So maybe this is a wrong urn format or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you can create a BIM 360 Docs Folder with commands endpoints, as you pointed out. For that you can use:

- [3-legged](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) token
- [2-legged](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/) token with `x-user-id` header, this should contain the Autodesk User ID obtained, for instance, from [GET users@me](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/users-@me-GET/) endpoint
- "pure" 2-legged token will return **bad request** (as of August/2017)

Sorry about the documentation, the endpoint to create BIM 360 Docs folder via Commands was released a couple weeks back and we're just finishing to write the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working. I suppose that only the user who created it will see the folder? Or does everybody within the project will see it?

Comment: Files and folders are project wise, unless you specify a different/specific access permission.

Comment: Thank you very much